# Access and SQL Server for reporting

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, vb6

Hopefully someone can help me understand/help how to proceed here. What I'm trying to do is this...I have a legacy VB6 application that has data stored in SQL Server, and all tables are connected to MS Access. I previously had a report done in Access however, the user requested that it be an extract in Excel. At this time I have a process in Access (Vba) that populates a tmp_table and my report uses the data from this table for the report. I'm trying to skip the Access report, and link the temp_table back to SQL Server 2012, so I can select the data and and create an Excel Extract. So what I'm hoping to do is this..

1. Users click report button (pass two dates [from] and [to] to an empty form in Access
2. Dates are used to run the process and populate the temp_table
3. Link this table to SQL-SERVER 2012
4. Select data, and manually build an extract in Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a great deal of jumping through hoops.

A VB6 program or even a VBA macro can use Jet/ACE to connect to and extract data from SQL Server and then write the result as a Worksheet or Range in an Excel workbook, creating the workbook if necessary.  Probably a single SQL statement involved for a simple extract/export.  No need for Excel Automation at all.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually decided to skip ACCESS all together. Going right from VB to Excel.